# Can't invoke function via URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-lambda, micronaut

I created a lambda function based on Micronaut and Kotlin. It provides two controllers,
"/" for just saying Hello World and
"/somefunc" for doing stuff.
When I execute it via CLI, it works as expected

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name MYFUNC --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload '{ "path": "/somefunc" }' response.json
```

When I call the tests on the lambda page https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home?region=eu-central-1#/functions/MYFUNC?tab=testing
, it works as expected

But when I call the public URL https://THEPUBLICURL.lambda-url.eu-central-1.on.aws/somefunc, it always gets the result of calling the "/" controller.
And when I call https://THEPUBLICURL.lambda-url.eu-central-1.on.aws/somefuncthatdoesnotexist, it also respondes with the reply of the "/" controller.

The function handler is set to io.micronaut.function.aws.proxy.MicronautLambdaHandler

What am I doing wrong when calling the public URL?

Edit: Here is the example code:

```
package com.example

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    run(*args)
}
@Controller
open class HomeController {
    @Get
    fun hello() = mapOf("message" to "Hello World")
    @Get("/somefunc")
    fun somefunc() = mapOf("message" to "Hello some world")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html the payload of the lambda includes a `rawPath` attribute, not a `path` attribute.

Therefore your lambda code should handle its routing based on *that* attribute. And your manual invocation should look like

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name MYFUNC --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload '{ "rawPath": "/somefunc" }' response.json
```

Comment: So I always have to supply a payload when calling  
https://THEPUBLICURL.lambda-url.eu-central-1.on.aws/
instead of simply calling  
https://THEPUBLICURL.lambda-url.eu-central-1.on.aws/somefunc ?

Comment: @MadCatERZ no!? You are just expecting the wrong payload. All you do is correct, except for expecting `path` instead of `rawPath`.

Comment: OK, to be more precise:
I just want to know why making a GET request on https://THEPUBLICURL.lambda-url.eu-central-1.on.aws/somefunc does not produce the result return value of the corresponding function
`@Get("/somefunc")

  fun somefunc(): Map<String, String> {`

Comment: @MadCatERZ no need to be more precise. It depends entirely on what `@Get` is supposed to do. It presumable expects a `path` in the request / event but there is no `path` to be found, just a `rawPath`. You have not shown any code for handling requests, I am just telling you that whatever code you have is wrong because it ignores `rawPath`.

Comment: so now I've added the whole code to my question. If it's a very common issue that you have to reconfigure Micronaut applications to handle some "rawPath" parameter, it's amazing that you hardy can find anything about in on Google or Stackoverlfow.

Comment: @MadCatERZ do you know when Lambda Function URL was released? Like half a year ago, that is quite a new feature. Quite possible that Micronaut does not support it yet out of the box.

Comment: Meanwhile I implementet a Node.js Lambda relying on event.rawPath, works almost instantly.
I'll do more research reagarding Micronaut vs Lamba
Thank you very much for your patience :-)

Answer (score 0):

So I finally find out: It's simply seems not to be possible to append paths to the public URL.
The solution is to use an API Gatweway for calling the Lambda